# Initialize separate CPU cores in bootloader

Tags: assembly, multiprocessing, bootloader

Am a newbie on bootloader development. I tried some basic stuffs like printing a string "Hello World" like things. I would like to ask some thing like ,

Is there any possibility for initializing cores in a multicore chip separately on a bootloader using asm/c/c++/mixed ? (like, i want to initialize the 1st core alone or 3rd core alone ) .

If it is possible , kindly share the code .

Comment: Have you searched Intels documentation? What did you find?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are saying about the "intel bootloader development kit" documentation ? if anything else kindly share the link here.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds a bit like someone saying, "Now that I've made a match-box car, I'd like to make a moped."  Basically, you REALLY need to have more practice before you get into writing your own bootloader.

Comment: @PatrickM : ok i will learn more as you said.. but what am asking is it really possible ? or any of you geeks tried this before ?

Comment: @VivekVetri: You may need to have a look at APIC and interprocessor interrupts. For what I have seen in code that was to be runned by more processors, it was simply just the first processor increased some value holding number of processors so when the second processor got to this part it got to know it's second so it jumped to some other code.

Comment: Take a look at [Pure64](https://github.com/ReturnInfinity/Pure64) - the code is very clear and concise. In fact it does exactly what you are asking!

Comment: If you're talking about x86 or ARM, [What does multicore assembly language look like?](//stackoverflow.com/q/980999) has examples for both.  But the x86 example *broadcasts* the SIPI (Startup Inter-Processor Interrupt) to all logical cores, instead of enumerating and making it possible to do it selectively.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Yes, and one can enumerate them by first finding the base of the ACPI table in memory, then find the MADT(APIC) table from that and then all the type 0 entries are entries for each processor including whether the processor should be ignored (ie: because hyperthreading disabled in BIOS, faulty cpu etc), its lapic id, lapic version etc.

Comment: @PeterCordes Normally you need to enumerate them first so you can tell if they've all started up successfully or not.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any possibility for initializing cores in a multicore chip separately on a bootloader using asm/c/c++/mixed ?

Yes, it's entirely possible.

> If it is possible , kindly share the code .

Just because it's possible doesn't mean that code exists; and even if the code exists it doesn't mean that it's small enough to paste here.

The reality is that to do it properly (on 80x86) you need to:

- if you're in real mode (e.g. a boot loader for BIOS) switch to protected mode and long mode
- parse tables (ACPI's MADT/APIC table, or Intel's MultiProcessor specification table if there's no ACPI) to determine where the local APIC/s are, how many other CPUs there are, which IDs those CPUs use. Note that just finding these tables (before you can parse them) may involve searching areas of the physical address space looking for signatures and checking checksums.
- establish some sort of time source you can use for delays and time-outs
- find/allocate some memory that is suitable (below 0x00100000, starting on a page boundary) for the AP CPU startup trampoline. For some cases this can be more complicated than you might assume (for UEFI there's no guarantee that any of the memory below 0x00100000 is free, you may need to call `exitBootServices()` before suitable memory becomes free, and you will probably need to initialize your own video output code before calling `exitBootServices()` so that you can display error messages, etc after you can no longer rely on UEFI's console support).
- initialize the AP startup trampoline, which typically involves copying into the memory you found/allocated, and may involve setting various values in the trampoline (e.g. address CPU should use for stack, etc). Of course this also means writing code in (16-bit real mode) assembly and typically involves more code to switch to protected mode or long mode, so that if/when the AP CPU starts the code in the trampoline can bring the CPU up to a state where the it can execute "normal" code.
- do the AP CPU startup sequence (which involves using the local APIC on one CPU to send a special sequence of interrupts to another CPU, with time delays and time-outs, and error handling).

Of course all of this is a lot of work, and most of it is work that is done for multiple reasons. For example, you might find the APCI (and/or Multiprocessor spec) tables and use them for 100 different things later, then you might initialize timer/s and use them for 100 different things later, you might initialize a physical memory manager and use it for 100 different things, etc. This means that the code to do these things ends up spread throughout boot (some in boot loader, some in other pieces of boot code, some in kernel), and it's "almost never" all in one convenient place (like "here's all the things for starting other CPU in this one file").